# Simple shadow on openGL shader language

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, shader, shadow

I am dealing into shaders and I want to make a very simple a dull shadow. Just like photoshop does on a layer. I need to do this on GLSL.

I've got this far by collecting bits and pieces of code from the web. But it's pretty bad.

Also, I need this to run on a phone, so it needs to be pretty efficient. So, yeah this one fails at both being efficient and looking like a shadow.

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4s2GDG

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to run this on phone you should not make shader similar to the shown one - it is way too complicated for a mobile device. It has loops which is an overkill for not very powerful mobile GPUs.

I'd better recommend you to do multiple render passes - one for object and one for shadow instead. Yes it will cause overdraw but if done properly it will perform better than such complicated shader. Even ping-pong rendering between 2 render targets is not a very computation-heavy task for modern GPU if done with simple shaders compared to shaders with loops - these ones are really slow. We've implemented simple blur which runs pretty smoothly even on *Adreno 200*. You can read about this here http://androidworks-kea.blogspot.com/2013/10/developers-notes-iii-simple-dof-effect.html and adopt this for your needs.